# Read service versions from ApplicationManifest.xml from within a service fabric application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

Packages for the service fabric can contain multiple services. Their version numbers are documented in ApplicationPackageRoot/ApplicationManifest.xml of the package:

```html
...
<ServiceManifestImport>
 <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="VotingDataPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.29" />
</ServiceManifestImport>
<ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="VotingWebPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.29" />
</ServiceManifestImport>
...
```

Question: **Is it possible to read this version information from one of the .NET services in the package?**

I want the web service in the package to read the version information from ApplicationManifest.xml and present it on his web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the servicecontext which is supplied to you in "runasync" method and call context.CodePackageActivationContext and drill down to the package versions.

Comment: Thanks! In the web controller I just had to overwrite the constructor to get the service context. Then the CodePackageVersion is accessible via context.CodePackageActivationContext.CodePackageVersion.